# VirtualBox Ubuntu guest on OS X Lion host: Curl won't work

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, osx-lion, curl

I'm trying to install some gems on an Ubuntu VM on OS X Lion using VirtualBox. I've narrowed my problem down to curl which is not responding at all. It seems to be going through some proxy local host thing. Does anyone know how to get this working? I really am clueless to this kind of thing. It times out after this output:

```
quickstart@qs10:~$ curl -v http://www.google.com
* About to connect() to proxy localhost port 3128 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3128 (#0)
> GET http://www.google.com HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.3 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.3 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.18
> Host: www.google.com
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
```

**Edit:**
I can ping google and wget does kinda the same thing...

Comment: What are your network settings in Ubuntu? More importantly: How is networking set up in VirtualBox? Can you connect to anything else using a browser?

Comment: Can you `ping google.com`? Considered trying `wget`?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answers. I edited my message with some more info.

Comment: @slhck I tried using various network settings on Virtual box. Nothing seemed to work. I am using Bridges Adapter at the moment.